# How can I change onClick, elements on ionic v4 React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to click  a button or an IonItemSliding and change the text or the color of an element.

```
                          <IonItemOptions side="start">
                            <IonItemOption color="success">Yes</IonItemOption>
                        </IonItemOptions>
                        <IonItemOptions side="end">
                            <IonItemOption color="danger"}>No</IonItemOption>
                        </IonItemOptions>
                    </IonItemSliding>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import React from 'react'
import { IonButton } from '@ionic/react'

export default function(){
  const [ text, setText ] = React.useState("Primary Button") 
  return(
    <IonButton 
      color="primary" 
      onClick={ () => setText("Clicked") }
    >
      { text }
    </IonButton>
  )
}
```